# Yii Relations Model

Tags: yii, relation, cgridview

I'm having a bad time trying to set relations in the following case.

I have a table *Person (id_person, name, id_mother, id_father)*

I know hot to make relations in model with foreign key for different tables. But in this case, *id_mother and id_father are mapped to other id_person* (hope I made my self clear).

this is what I tried

```
 public function relations() {
     return array(
            'father'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PERSON', 'id_person'),
            'mother'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PERSON', 'id_person'),
     );
}
```

And I want their names in CGridVew

```
$data->father->NAME
$data->mother->NAME
```

What I have to do in this case?

Comment: In this case you have lazy load. Try with property into criteria or set together property as true ('father'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PERSON', 'id_person', 'together')). Also you can use: $data->father ?  $data->father->NAME : '';

Comment: together worked, but what do I do when id_mother and id_father are null? It says that relation 0 is not defined

Comment: Then test if (isnull($data->father->NAME)) ....

Answer (score 2):

I think you defined wrong relations. 
Relation method should be like this:

```
public function relations() {
     return array(
            'father'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PERSON', 'id_father'),
            'mother'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PERSON', 'id_mother'),
     );
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It won't work, because id_father and id_mother are like foreign key to id_person. But they are all in the same table. In this case I want the name of them